# Is it possible to output a fixed number of groups in SQL even if there are fewer groups in the result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a diagram based on an SQL query. The diagram should show every 12 months of the current year, even if some of them are still in the future.

My SQL query is something like this:

```
SELECT
     MONTH (created) as m,
     sum (price) as s
FROM
   product
WHERE
   YEAR (created) = 2020
GROUP BY
   m
```

Of course, this only shows results for the current or past months, which also have any entries.

Is it possible

- to formulate the query so that 12 groups are displayed in any case and
- if there is no group it gets a default value of 0?

Comment: It seems you are trying to visualize data you may or may not have (yet) - For this reason, I would concentrate on visualizing the data you do have instead of 'inventing' data you do not and visualizing 'fake' data.  What I am trying to say is: work with real data and choose how to display it by using your diagramming tool to add the default value when none exists.  It's almost always best to deal with real data and choose how to present it (today it may be a default of zero, tomorrow it might be something else)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I had somehow in my head, the SQL = MYSQL as default, if nothing else mentioned. :) But of course you are right. I added the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, left join it to a collection of all 12 months. This is MySQL (because you used GROUP BY alias, which I think is MySQL only, maybe Postgres too):

```
WITH months as (
 SELECT 1 as m
 UNION ALL SELECT 2
 UNION ALL SELECT 3
 UNION ALL SELECT 4
 UNION ALL SELECT 5
 UNION ALL SELECT 6
 UNION ALL SELECT 7
 UNION ALL SELECT 8
 UNION ALL SELECT 9 
 UNION ALL SELECT 10
 UNION ALL SELECT 11
 UNION ALL SELECT 12 
)

SELECT
  m.m,
  sum (p.price) as s
FROM
  months m
  LEFT JOIN product p 
  ON 
    m.m = MONTH(p.created) AND
    p.created > '2020-01-01' and p.Created < '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY
  m.m
```

Months that don't match will have a NULL, which will sum as 0

You should try and prefer to not use functions like YEAR() in the WHERE clause because they mean that indexes can't be used; instead leave the table data alone and put a ranged search in instead

If your MySQL is old and doesn't support CTE, make that a subquery instead. If your database isn't MySQL/Pg, or it has to select from something you can make it select from a table that has only one row

---

An alternative trick that doesn't employ a join, would be to union a load of zero months in; they wont contribute to sums but will provide a month with 0:

```
SELECT
   m,
   sum (price) as s
FROM
(
   SELECT MONTH(created) as m, price FROM product WHERE created >= '2020-01-01' and created < '2021-01-01'
   UNION ALL SELECT 1, 0 UNION ALL SELECT 2, 0 UNION ALL SELECT 3, 0 
   UNION ALL SELECT 4, 0 UNION ALL SELECT 5, 0 UNION ALL SELECT 6, 0 
   UNION ALL SELECT 7, 0 UNION ALL SELECT 8, 0 UNION ALL SELECT 9, 0 
   UNION ALL SELECT 10, 0 UNION ALL SELECT 11, 0 UNION ALL SELECT 12, 0 
) x
GROUP BY
   m
```

If you have a table dedicated to numbers and dates, the union all block can be replaced with a call to it. If you're on Postgres, it has a series generator that can [do cool things](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-srf.html)

Comment: Not sure if I am wrong here, but doesn't LEFT JOIN coupled with a WHERE statement on the right table act as an INNER JOIN. I do not think you will get the results he is looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a table to store the groups you want to display.

```
CREATE TABLE twelveMonths (intMonth int);
INSERT INTO twelveMonths VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

SELECT
     MONTH (created) as m,
     sum(coalesce(price,0)) as s
FROM twelveMonths
LEFT JOIN product ON product.MONTH(created)=twelveMonths.intMonth and YEAR (created) = 2020
    GROUP BY m
```

If you do not want to create a table you can use a CTE, temp table or table variablem or you can hack it with an ugly subselect:

```
SELECT
     MONTH (created) as m,
     sum(coalesce(price,0)) as s
FROM
      (
   select 1 as intMonth UNION ALL select 2 UNION ALL select 3 UNION ALL select 4 UNION ALL 
   select 5 UNION ALL select 6 UNION ALL select 7 UNION ALL select 8 UNION ALL 
   select 9 UNION ALL select 10 UNION ALL select 11 UNION ALL select 12 ) twelveMonths
LEFT JOIN product ON product.MONTH(created)=twelveMonths.intMonth and YEAR (created) = 2020
GROUP BY m
```